# How to begin database transaction in acumatica framework?

Tags: acumatica

How to begin database transaction in acumatica framework?
is there any way to execute bulk insert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you to look in T300 course of Acumatica. There you can find about PXTransactionScope which will imitate transaction.

If to consider bulk insert as insert with will insert records in database without tracking data into .ldf file of database, then I don't think there is a way to do it with Acumatica.

If you still have desire to execute transaction, then I propose you to write stored procedure, which takes as paramether xml, and inside of stored procedure to make transaction. I just need to warn you that it is strictly unrecommended way by Acumatica. Then you can call procedure in the following way: PXDatabase.Execute(). More details you can find http://blog.zaletskyy.com/execute-stored-procedure-in-acumatica

Answer (score 0):

You might need to utilize a Web Service to do this.  I'm not 100% sure how these work, but they can be found under System > Integration > Configure > Web Services.

I'm also not sure why this question got downvoted... it seems like a fairly legit question to me.